# what does discontiguous predicate mean?

Tags: prolog

what is the issue with the following script?

```
want(grocerystore).
available(grocerystore).
want(X):-
   available(X).
can(grocerystore):-
   want(grocerystore),
   \+work(walmart),
   available(grocerystore).
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, as you haven't shown any output. Please edit your question accordingly. Also - questions along the lines of "why isn't my code working" are off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

"Discontiguous predicate" means that you defined more than one clause for a given predicate, but defined the clause of a different predicate in between. Prolog wants all of the clauses of a given predicate together.

Here's an example of what properly defined Prolog looks like with multiple clauses for a given predicate or fact:

```
person(sally).
person(sue).

dog(fido).
dog(fluffy).
```

You can see all of the `person` facts are together, and all of the `dog` facts are together.

Here is an example of a "discontiguous predicate":

```
person(sally).
dog(fido).

person(sue).
dog(fluffy).
```

Here, the `person` facts are "interrupted" by a `dog` fact (and *vice versa*).

The same issue applies to predicates as it does to facts. In your case, two different `want` clauses are "interrupted" by the `available` fact:

```
want(grocerystore).
available(grocerystore).   % 'available' clause occurs between two 'want' clauses
want(X) :- ...
```

Easy fix in this case:

```
available(grocerystore).

want(grocerystore).
want(X) :- ...
```

There may be other issues with your program, but I'm only addressing the question you have about "discontiguous predicate".

Comment: "*Prolog wants all of the clauses of a given predicate together.*" - why does Prolog want that? o_O

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler : You could accidentally add clauses to an existing predicate when the same name is used. And when you use the predicate, the clause you wrote might not be executed. Thus we have Spooky bugs.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler in addition to what rajashekar said, you really don't want all of the clauses for a given predicate scattered about because they logically belong together. They form a set of rules about one relationship that you are defining.

Comment: @rajashekar, lurker, thank you