# How to compile a prolog question correctly?

Tags: prolog

I am working on a prolog problem and need some help here.

```
/*Write a predicate listtran(L,E) which translates a list of Latin number words 
 * to the corresponding list of English number words. */

%% predicate
listtran(L,E).

%% clauses
tran(unus,one).
tran(duo,two).
tran(tres,three).
tran(quattuor,four).
tran(quinque,five).
tran(sex,six).
tran(septem,seven).
tran(octo,eight).
tran(novem,nine).

%% rules
% base case: empty list
listtran([], []).
% inductive cases: 
listtran([L | T0], [E | T1]) :-
  tran(L, E), % translate the head of the list
  listtran(T0, T1). % translate the tail of the list, using recursion
```

What is needed to be written in predicates and query to test:

```
?- listtran([unus,novem,duo],X).
should give:
X = [one,nine,two].
```

and

```
?- listtran(X,[one,seven,six,two]).
it should return:
X = [unus,septem,sex,duo].
```

Also, what can be done to avoid the error message:

```
Clauses of listtran/2 are not together in the source-file
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a discontigous predicate error.

Prolog is complaining that all the clauses of a predicate are not defined in one place. You should just delete the `listtrans(L, E).`(why is it even there?) at the start and the rest should work fine.

An explanation of the error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40614467/4437190